# Как расшифровать ключ IV Aes Rsa-2048?

Tags: c#, rsa, aes

Имеется данный исходный код, которым шифруется ключ и вектор.

Как при использование расшифровки AES алгоритмом расшифровать ключ и вектор ключа алгоритмом RSA ?

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class RSACSPSample
{

    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {       //initialze the byte arrays to the public key information.
            byte[] PublicKey = {214,46,220,83,160,73,40,39,201,155,19,202,3,11,191,178,56,
                                   74,90,36,248,103,18,144,170,163,145,87,54,61,34,220,222,
                                   207,137,149,173,14,92,120,206,222,158,28,40,24,30,16,175,
                                   108,128,35,230,118,40,121,113,125,216,130,11,24,90,48,194,
                                   240,105,44,76,34,57,249,228,125,80,38,9,136,29,117,207,139,
                                   168,181,85,137,126,10,126,242,120,247,121,8,100,12,201,171,
                                   38,226,193,180,190,117,177,87,143,242,213,11,44,180,113,93,
                                   106,99,179,68,175,211,164,116,64,148,226,254,172,147};

            byte[] Exponent = {1,0,1};
      
            //Values to store encrypted symmetric keys.
            byte[] EncryptedSymmetricKey;
            byte[] EncryptedSymmetricIV;

            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            //Create a new instance of RSAParameters.
            RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();

            //Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
            RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = PublicKey;
            RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = Exponent;

            //Import key parameters into RSA.
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

            //Create a new instance of the Aes class.
            Aes aes = Aes.Create();

            //Encrypt the symmetric key and IV.
            EncryptedSymmetricKey = RSA.Encrypt(aes.Key, false);
            EncryptedSymmetricIV = RSA.Encrypt(aes.IV, false);

            Console.WriteLine("Aes Key and IV have been encrypted with RSACryptoServiceProvider."); 
        }
        //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
        //to the console.
        catch(CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Странная операция, зачем шифровать ключи одного алгоритма с помощью другого? Выглядит бессмысленно и неэффективно. Зачем всё это?

Comment: Для доп защиты от расшифровки